# What are the similarities and differences between SAP BusinessObjects and XS Engine?

Tags: webserver, sapui5, business-objects, application-server, hana-xs

I have an application developed using sapUI5. The next step would be to host the app on a web server/application server.

That being said, there are 2 options to consider:

1. SAP XS Engine
2. SAP BusinessObjects

I'm pretty familiar with how this would work with XS Engine. The XS Engine is a lightweight application server embedded in SAP HANA that can be used to layer procedural logic and Web services on top of HANA tables and views.

Here is a diagram showing its structure (XS Engine):

[image]

With that in mind, how does Sap BusinessObjects compare to XS Engine? With XS being directly on HANA, BOBJ has a few other layers in between. Only I cannot understand what they are, and how they work. How is BusinessObjects able to 'talk' to the HANA database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BOBJ(3-Tier Architecture)**

1. Flexibility of having different Netweaver (ABAP/Java) Gateway server and Backend server, and it could be m:n connections b/w them.
2. Backend server could connect to any DB. (need not be HANA)Because of which you can easily and with little disruption integrate SAP HANA functionality into your current architecture.

**SAP HANA Native Application – Using SAP HANA XS:**

1. If you are building a new application from scratch which is SAP HANA specific, SAP HANA XS is a better option. With SAP HANA Extended Application Services you can build and deploy your application completely self-contained within SAP HANA.
2. This provides an opportunity for a lower cost of development and ownership. It also provides better performance because of the closeness of the application and control flow logic to the database.

[image]

> This is quite a broader topic. I am open to add other points if I've
>   missed.

Comment: Thanks Sunil, this diagram is very helpful. Assuming that the light blue represents BusinessObjects, how/what parts of SAP BusinessObjects are being used here, it's not clear just by looking at the diagram!

Comment: Also, how does Business Objects make calls to the database, and how is it exposed to the frontend application(we know that XS Engine does this via OData)?

Comment: @Kode_12 since you have asked in the different question, I have answered there. Ideally this wasn't the right picture.